# Max file size and max repository size in Git?

Tags: git

I'm looking to have Git as the primary source control for my employer (250 people) company. Before proceeding further I would like to have answers to the following questions.

1. Does Git have any specific  max file size limit that it can handle? If so, what is it?
2. What is the max repository size recommended by Git? This would help me determine the housekeeping I should set on the repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File number and size limits in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/q/984707/456814).

Comment: I recently had a branch screwed up because of commit and push to origin files greater than 50mb. I stored the files offline and had to re-create the branch. I presume it's possible that Github will vary this limit for you depending on how much you pay.

Answer (score 52):

As mentioned in [Git limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984707/what-are-the-git-limits/984973#984973), Git has no file size or file number limit per se.
But it:

- Won't manage large files too well (which is why a project like [Git-BigFiles](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/git-bigfiles) exists)
- Tag every file within its repository, which is why, if you have many different sets of files which each have their own development life-cycle, it is better to use *several* Git repositories anyway (see [true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)).
  That approach is more suited to a [component-driven development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933723/what-is-component-driven-development/933735#933735), and is [quite different from the SVN external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131912/why-are-git-submodules-incompatible-with-svn-externals/3132221#3132221).

Comment: Git does not have size limits but Github and most other hosts do.

Comment: @Ring I agree: *hosting* Git repositories comes with its own limitations.

Answer (score 29):

Rule of thumb: 1GB per repository, 100MB per file

For best performance, github recommend repositories be kept under 1GB each. This limit is easy to stay within if large files (typically, binaries) are kept out of the repository. If your repository exceeds 1GB, you might receive a polite email from support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository to bring it back down under 1GB.

In addition, we place a strict limit of files exceeding 100 MB in size. For more information on why this is, see our article on working with large files.

Look at: [Managing Large Files / What is my disk quota?](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota)
(it refers to both GitHub and Git capabilities.)

Comment: I think this answer is better than I initially thought. His source backs up what he says.

Comment: Here a slightly broader answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605544/7127519

Comment: As you mentioned _"email from support requesting [...] to bring it back down under 1GB"_, is there some goto documentation about how to?

Comment: This answer should be deleted since the question is about git, not about GitHub. For a thread about GitHub limits, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768454/repository-size-limits-for-github-com).

Answer (score 3):

As of 2018-04-20 [Git for Windows has a bug](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1063) which effectively limits the file size to 4GB max using that particular implementation (this bug [propagates to lfs as well](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2434)).