# RPC Failed result 22 http code 404

Tags: git, bonobo

Im using Bonobo Git Server and everything looks fine. Im movin all my old SVN repos to GIT and even with big repos (about 3.5 GB) with +760 commits the "git svn clone" and "git push" is working really fine.

But not with a tiny repository: it has just 3Mb (uncompressed) and just 1 commit. 
The message i always get is:

```
efrror: RPC Failed; result=22, HTTP code = 404
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I already change the bonobo webconfig as recomened [here](http://gisgeek.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/bonobo-git-server-remote-end-hung-up.html) and I already did [this config command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702731/git-fails-when-pushing-commit-to-github).

So, anyone has any other clue?

Comment: Did you ever find out what the problem was in this scenario?

Comment: Not 100% positive that this is the solution but it fixed my problems pushing ~40MB to Bonobo running  on a data center WS2008R2 machine: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2634328

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533379/git-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-404

Answer (score 7):

Based in http://gisgeek.blogspot.com/2012/03/bonobo-git-server-remote-end-hung-up.html.

This is the solution

Solution:
Modify the web.config file in the root of Bonobo.Git.Server (C:\initpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\Web.config) and up the limits on the following lines:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" /> 


<security>
   <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="102400" />
```

In both cases "102400" was replaced with "999999999" and the push worked!

Comment: Also hepls with errors like `error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054`

Answer (score 2):

I have met a similar error when I try to push my local git repo to gitlab. The complete error message is:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 64 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 288 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 404
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I solved this issue by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49305337/6064933). Specifically, I add a `.git` after the remote repo URL:

```
# add .git suffix to the ORIGINAL_URL
git remote set-url origin ORIGINAL_URL.git
```

After that, I can push to remote gitlab repo successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified my file and commit the code again, everything was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while trying to clone from a source repo on Google Cloud using the gcloud SDK tool with Anaconda3:

```
fatal: The remote end fhung up unexpectedly
atal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Command '[u'git', u'clone', u'https://source.developers.google.com/p/propane-highway-202915/r/arise-ds-program', u'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\arise-ds-program', u'--config', u'credential.helper=', u'--config', u'credential.helper=!gcloud.cmd auth git-helper --account=steve.deve89@gmail.com --ignore-unknown $@']' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

Fortunately, I was able to solve this by switching to the disabling Windows Defender Firewall (including other anti-virus software) and switching to a base environment in conda.

*PS*: The environment I got this issue earlier was a conda py 2.7 environment (while the base env was conda py 3.x), so it might be as a  result of permissions (0n Windows), or incompatibility issues.