# Teamcity agent - Failed to perform checkout on agent. HTTP code = 404

Tags: git, gitlab, teamcity

First time I'm using teamcity and I've installed a agent on the server itself. When I run the build I get the following error message.

Is there somewhere I should specify git creds for agent to read them? Is that why the following error is displayed? I've already added creds  to `vcs root` in project settings.

gitlab is hosted on the localhost, agent is on localhost and teamcity is also on localhost.

```
Failed to perform checkout on agent: '/usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=/root/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/pass2043620868177620056 fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master' command failed.
exit code: 128
stderr: error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 404
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

FYI, I know this question looks similar to other questions but none of them the same exact error - `HTTP code = 404`  and `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix.

The solution was to put the `.git` on the end of the url in `vcs root`.

[Git error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533379/git-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-404?rq=1)