# Why would GAE repo hang?

Tags: git, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

My GCE git repo was working fine and then I tried playing with `appcfg.py update` and it failed due to too many files (files that weren't checked into git).

When I git pushed again, it hangs and then says an RPC call failed. The output is here:

```
Pushing to https://source.developers.google.com/p/my-project-name/
Counting objects: 660, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (595/595), done.
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
Writing objects: 100% (660/660), 1.30 MiB | 650.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 660 (delta 96), reused 10 (delta 3)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 502
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

**Update**

The output now says something slightly different about the RPC failure:

```
Pushing to https://source.developers.google.com/p/<redacted>/
Counting objects: 660, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (595/595), done.
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
Writing objects: 100% (660/660), 1.30 MiB | 934.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 660 (delta 96), reused 10 (delta 3)
Unable to rewind rpc post data - try increasing http.postBuffer
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702731/git-fails-when-pushing-commit-to-github), the issue is because the size of the files (or the total size) is bigger than expected and generates an error.

In GAE there's a maximum of 10,000 files that you can upload to your application. This doesn't seem to be the cause, unless you already had 9601 on it.

Probably you could follow the instructions in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702731/git-fails-when-pushing-commit-to-github) and try to increase the size of http.postBuffer:

> I found that the problem may be files that are large. I had one update
>   that would not push even though I had successful pushes up to that
>   point. There was only one file in the commit but it happened to be
>   1.6M
>
> So I added the following config change
>
> `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`

Answer (score 0):

Increasing http postbuffer size resolved my problem.

To get this resolved you have to go to path of git cloned folder from where you are trying to commit and then execute below command.

git config http.postBuffer 324244000