# Multiple push errors w/ git

Tags: git, push

Getting several errors while trying to do a push.

**Notes & attempted fixes**:

- I've updated to the latest git (2.10.0)
- I've increased my [buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702731/git-fails-when-pushing-commit-to-github)
- I have multiple repositories under different projects, only one of
  them is encountering the error.
- There are no large files, mostly text & a single (small) image.
- I am using Sourcetree on Windows 7 but have also tried cmd
- I've tried branching master to a dev branch

**Error:**

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master  
Fatal: ArgumentException encountered.  
Fatal: ArgumentException encountered.  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor  
Pushing to https://[myusername]@bitbucket.org/[myteam]/ada.git  
error: failed to push some refs to https://[myusername]@bitbucket.org/[myteam]/ada.git
```

I did manage to find one entry on ArgumentException [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/286). It does appear to be a bug, but that does not explain the other errors. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Check `git config http.postBuffer` and `pack.windowMemory`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an empty folder, pulling down my remote repository and then copy/pasted the local files from the previous folder (except for /.git/) into the new local repository.

It recognized my changes and I was able to push them just fine.