# Why are my files not getting pushed on github?

Tags: git, github

I try pushing the files and wait for the process to end. Neither the process ends not I can see any change on github.

```
C:\git\btprc\btprc>git push origin master
Counting objects: 5847, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5845/5845), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5847/5847), 867.55 MiB | 13.45 MiB/s, done.
Total 5847 (delta 3406), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by the process not ending, as the output you pasted shows that changes were successfully pushed onto your repo, but is it stalled at the Total line? Here's a link to a similar post: [Git fails when pushing commit to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702731/git-fails-when-pushing-commit-to-github)

It could be that you've added a file that exceeded the size limitations for your repo, and the push is stalling. You would simply have to wait a longer amount of time for the process to complete, with a chance of another output line at the end that will state failed files pushed.

If that's the case, your best bet is to compress various assets via clean and smudge. This will convert large files into txt format, and revert back upon call.

```
git config filter.compress.clean gzip
git config filter.compress.smudge gzip -d
```

For more info on that, check out this post: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

If you mean to add new files onto the repo, and don't know how, try using `git add <FILES>`. This will mark the specified files to be added into your next commit. For example, if you want to include all files in a specific directory, use `git add *`, `git add -A`, or `git add --all`. For more info on that, check out https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add