# GitHub, push error: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github

I now cannot push my local commit to the github repo. I received an error message:

```
Counting objects: 76, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (75/75), done.
Writing objects: 100% (76/76), 5.23 MiB | 24.67 MiB/s, done.
Total 76 (delta 45), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: early EOF
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I've tried some solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to), nothing works.

I also tried to push another project to rule out network issue. It succeeded, although taking some time.

I ran `git fsck`, receiving

```
git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (3831/3831), done.
```

Comment: Looks like server issue

Comment: @loa_in_ I succeeded in pushing another project. Is it possible that only this project cannot be pushed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

---

**File size**

Let's try with a bigger post buffer as described [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-httppostBuffer).

```
git config http.postBuffer 100000000
```

> http.postBuffer
>
> Maximum size in bytes of the buffer used by smart HTTP transports when POSTing data to the remote system. For requests larger than this buffer size, HTTP/1.1 and Transfer-Encoding: chunked is used to avoid creating a massive pack file locally. Default is 1 MiB, which is sufficient for most requests.

*Idea from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605544/581076](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605544/581076_)*

---

**Original thought**

This looks like a server issue.

If you have been able to push before, I suggest trying again after waiting some more time.

Comment: But I succeeded in pushing another project. Is it possible that only this project cannot be pushed?

Comment: Hm... do you have binary or other special files in the changes you're pushing?

Comment: Also what the other project from the same machine and for the same github user?

Comment: both are from the same machine and the same github user

Comment: The project that cannot be pushed successfully is a GitHub blog. all changes are md and png files