# error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining when pushing my android project to github

Tags: git, github, push, repo

I am having a problem trying to push my code to github. This is the error that I am facing I have tried few solutions that I have found but they all seem not to be working. This is the error that I am facing:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have tried to resolve the error by using this solution that I found in stack overflow but It has not worked

> git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000

I even tried to replace http with ssh but it still did not work

Comment: Please see [the Git FAQ}(https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) for why you should not need to set `http.postBuffer` and why it indicates a problem if you do.

Answer (score 0):

After trying most of the solutions here:[git push gives: error: RPC failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55818445/git-push-gives-error-rpc-failed-curl-18-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read).
None of the solutions worked for me.

I got a solution inspired by this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66060728/14534473) and it worked all I had to was to change my internet connection since it was slow. Seems slow internet causes this error

Comment: Please help others with similar problems by posting what exactly was the solution that fixed your issue.