# git pull gives error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, git-merge

I tried to pull changes from master which is already a huge repo. My internet connections are very stable and this error is showing up for me recently. Tested out the internet connectivity speed and this issue is only occurring in my machine.

```
remote: Counting objects: 100% (86150/86150), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Any help with this issue will be appreciable.

**Note**: When I tried searching for this issue, everyone had faced it for `push` and not for pull. Therefore, creating a new question regarding this issue.

Comment: the repo is hosted on a service provider?

Comment: @eftshift0 no it is not hosted on service provider

Comment: what do the logs say on the server?

Comment: @eftshift0 sorry got confused. the repo is hosted in gitlab

Comment: No problem..... I should have specified  it is the _remote_ repo. Do you have pointers to the answers talking about this failure on push?

Comment: Yeah. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55818445/git-push-gives-error-rpc-failed-curl-18-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read)

Comment: Looks like a timeout, either on your end, on GitLab's end, and/or on some device between you and GitLab. How long does it run before you get that message?

Comment: @JimRedmond it runs around like 2-3 mins max