# I get stuck with git bash fatal error report

Tags: git, git-push

When running `git push -u origin master`, I receive an error message  unexpectedly. I have tried pushing to Github and also Gitlab. I get the same error.

```
error: unable to rewind rpc post data - try increasing http.postBuffer
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

[image: Error report]

It is okay when I try to run `git add .` and `git commit -m "commit image"`.

The data I am committing is separate images. There are more than 41,000 image files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git fails when pushing commit to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702731/git-fails-when-pushing-commit-to-github)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+unable+to+rewind+rpc+post+data+try+increasing+http.postBuffer

Answer (score 2):

Your error message states that we should `try increasing http.postBuffer`.

The [git documentation for `http.postBuffer`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config/1.7.8#git-config-httppostBuffer) tells us that the default maximum is 1 MiB.

> Maximum size in bytes of the buffer used by smart HTTP transports when POSTing data to the remote system. For requests larger than this buffer size, HTTP/1.1 and Transfer-Encoding: chunked is used to avoid creating a massive pack file locally. **Default is 1 MiB, which is sufficient for most requests.**

You're right to note that your images are numerous. Because you have 41627 new objects to push, the total size of the files you're writing is 2.25 GiB. This is far larger than the 1 MiB limit.

### Increasing `http.postBuffer`

You could try increasing the buffer size, as the error message states.

You can increase this to 3 GiB by setting `git config http.postBuffer 3221225472`.

I would recommend against doing this, because 3 GiB is much, much larger than the 1 MiB default.

### Git Large File Storage

Storing large non-text-based files is a common problem with git, and a solution which exists is [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/). It replaces your images in Git with pointers to files hosted on GitHub.com.

It offers the "same access controls and permissions" as when working with a remote host like GitHub.

> *Keep the same access controls and permissions for large files as the rest of your Git repository when working with a remote host like GitHub.*

Generally, git isn't made for versioning binary files. It's best for tracking text-based content.

Comment: `$ git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 41628, done.
Counting objects: 100% (41628/41628), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (41626/41626), done.
Writing objects: 100% (41627/41627), 2.25 GiB | 5.78 MiB/s, done.
Total 41627 (delta 0), reused 41627 (delta 0)

error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly Everything up-to-date`