# Files not being added to repository on Github-- repository appears empty

Tags: git, github, repository, git-add

I added a new repository to Github. For some reason, my files didn't show up after following the command prompts. I checked Git to confirm that my website was in the repository and it shows that it is. I then made small changes to each file and tried re-adding them to the repository. It still shows that I don't have any files. This is my last command[My last commands )adding files)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adya6.png)

Comment: Please use cut-and-paste for text, rather than posting an image of the text (see [ask]). But in any case the line about failing to resolve the name `github.com` means that your `git push` never even started; that's why your new commit did not make it to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused in incorrect proxy settings , or error typing name, make sure you're using the exact URL of whatever you're trying to do.

Try these commands.

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Also set user- name and user-email.

```
git config --global user.name "user name"
git config --global user.email "user email"
```

If these don't solve your problem, try this:

I had issues like this and there is no one specific set of instructions to resolve. however i tried running this command and it worked for me

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Then run

```
git remote  set-url origin <repository link>
```

After commiting your new changes try running this command if regular push gives you an error

```
git push origin <branch>  --force
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I tried it a few times and kept getting this message. "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"                                                                                   I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702731/git-fails-when-pushing-commit-to-github but none of the suggestions resolved the issue...